# Why is my webpack bundle so big when I replaced script tags in html with imports in an entry file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I am refactoring an Angularjs app to be a React app. The Angular app had a whole bunch of script tags in the `index.html`, stuff like:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/Chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.tpl.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
<script src='bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.min.js'></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert-dev.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/store/dist/store2.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.min.js"></script>
(...)
```

In porting this to webpack, I removed those script tags and replaced them with imports in an entry file `index.js`, that looks like the following:

```
// dependencies from angular legacy
import '../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';
import '../node_modules/lodash/lodash.min.js';
import '../node_modules/Chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js';
import '../node_modules/pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min.js';
import '../node_modules/pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js';
import '../node_modules/angular/angular.min.js';
import '../node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js';
import '../node_modules/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js';
import '../node_modules/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js';
import '../node_modules/angular-messages/angular-messages.min.js';
import '../node_modules/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js';
import '../node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.min.js';
import '../node_modules/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js';
import '../node_modules/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.min.js';
import '../node_modules/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.tpl.min.js';
import '../node_modules/angular-touch/angular-touch.min.js';
import '../node_modules/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.min.js';
import '../node_modules/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.min.js';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js';
import '../node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert-dev.js';
import '../node_modules/store2/dist/store2.min.js';

import '../node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js';
import '../node_modules/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.min.js';
import '../node_modules/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.tpl.min.js';
import '../node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js';
import '../node_modules/ui-select/dist/select.min.js';
(...)
```

What I noticed is that the webpack bundle is very huge, at 26mb. When I load the new page I have, Chrome Dev Tools tells me "Transferred" is 7.7mb but "Resources" is like 27mb.

Also, now with these imports, I have multiple versions of Angular in my node_modules.

I used `webpack-bundle-analyzer`, and got the following:
[image]

So a few questions:

- in that pic, how come I have `angular.js` and `angular.min.js`? In my imports I only have `import '../node_modules/angular/angular.min.js';`
- What does the difference between transferred and resources in this example imply?

Comment: You are probably better off importing the specific things you need rather than the full files, like `import $ from 'jQuery';` rather than `import 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';`. This will help webpack do its tree shaking to remove unused code.

Comment: I agree, but I am in the process of converting this legacy Angular app that I did not write to React. It will be a hybrid app while I convert it. So yeah, the objective is to import specific things instead of these imports you see, but that's not possible right now, as I have a lot of files depending on globals